# Как из массива Int удалить все нечётные элементы?

Tags: массивы, swift, int

Имеется функция, которая создает массив значений от 0 до 100. Необходимо удалить все нечётные элементы. Я пробовал добавлять проверку `x%2 != 0`, но тогда элементы ожидаемо сдвигаются на место удаленного элемента и не выходит как надо.

````
func hundred() -> Array<Int> {
    
    var array = [Int]()
    var i = 0
    
    repeat {
        array.append(i)
        i += 1
        }
    while i <= 100
    
    return array
}

let arrayNew = hundred()
print(arrayNew)```
````

Comment: замечательно, что вы нашли решение, которое вас устроило. Но оно такое же бесполезное для других, как и вопрос. Непонятно ни что должно получиться в итоге, ни почему не устроил вариант с x%2 != 0 (кстати, как именно он выглядел),

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение через `filter`

````
func hundred() -> [Int] {
    
    var array = [Int]()
    var i = 0
    
    repeat {
        array.append(i)
        i += 1
        }
    while i <= 100
    print(array)
    return array
}

let arrayNew = hundred()

var arrayNewFlat = arrayNew.map {String($0)}

var toDelete = arrayNew.filter {$0 % 2 != 0 }
print(toDelete)```
````